# Prove that $a_j=b_j$ for the $2$ sequences $a$ and $b$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, solution-verification

> Let $n$ is a natural number and $(n,6)=1$. Given $2$ sequences $a$ and
>   $b$ such that $a_1>a_2>\ldots a_n$ and $b_1>b_2>\ldots b_n$. And for
>   all $1 \leq j < k <l \leq n$, it is given that
>   $a_j+a_k+a_l=b_j+b_k+b_l$. Prove that $a_j=b_j$ for all $j$.

I don't know if this question is easy or not, but I did prove it without using much given information. Please tell the mistake in it.

> First substitute $k=2$ and $j=1$ and consider $2$ $l's$ $l_1$ and
>   $l_2$ and then subtract the $2$ equations to get
>   $a_{l_{2}}-b_{l_{2}}=a_{l_{1}}-b_{l_{1}}$. Now substitute $1,2,3$ and
>   $2,3,4$ and then subtract to get a similar equation. Now substitute
>   $1,3,4$ to get $a_1+a_3+a_4=b_1+b_3+b_4$. From this equation and the
>   previous one, it implies $a_j-b_j=0$ and the result follows.

I did not use half of the given information and I know I am going wrong somewhere, but where.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I think $(n,6)=1$ is just so that $n$ is not $2,3$ or $4$.

Comment: The sequences are formed by **real** numbers, right?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything wrong with your approach.  If I may paraphrase it (and replace your condition on n with $n≥5$):
For each $l\in (3,4, 5, ..., n)$ we have:
$$a_1+a_2+a_l = b_1+b_2+b_l$$
Whence $(a_l- b_l)$ is independent of l, at least for $l≥3$. Let $\Delta$ denote the common difference $(a_l- b_l)$ for $l≥3$.  Now, so long as n is at least 5 we can look at the sum $a_3+a_4+a_5$ but on the one hand that equals $b_3+b_4+b_5$ by assumption and on the other it equals $b_3+b_4+b_5+3\Delta$.  Hence $\Delta=0$.  Thus all the terms coincide except (possibly) the first two.  But of course we have $a_1+a_3+a_4 = b_1+b_3+b_4 = b_1+a_3+a_4$ which tells us that $a_1=b_1$ and similarly for the second term.

Just to say:  You have specified a very large number of equations.  It is not surprising that they determine the system nor that you could ignore a bunch of them.